# Putting 2 dimensional numpy arrays into a 3 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to keep adding numpy arrays to another array in python.
let's say I have the following arrays:

```
arraytotal = np.array([])
array1 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1]) 
array2 = np.array([2,2,2,2,2])
```

and I want to append array1 and array2 into arraytotal. However, when I use:

```
arraytotal.append[array1]
```

it tells me:

> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

how can I append array1 and array2 into arraytotal?

Comment: Adding an array to some other array is costly (needs to be replaced; like adding an element to a classic C array instead of a list which is faster). Just collect your arrays (in a list for example) and use np.vstack/np.hstack (depending on your desired shape). I'm also not getting the multiple 2d->3d stuff you describe. Your example looks more like multiple 1d -> 2d. The more simple approach: create list of lists and convert the final data to an array.

Comment: This syntax is horribly wrong, and it's not clear what you intended it to mean. Also, you don't seem to be counting dimensions correctly.

Comment: Thanks. and you're right, I shouldn't have mentioned it was going from 2D to 3D if I wasn't willing to include how the 2D files were drawn up. Basically, each item in listx and listy give the coordinates for a pixel, and the value that is returned is based on the rgb values of each of the pixels within a certain frame centered on that value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "horribly wrong," but I understand it's confusing. let me see what I can do to make it easier to understand

Comment: oh NOW I see what you mean by wrong

Comment: Try `np.concatenate` or `np.hstack` to merge two array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should append the arrays onto a regular python list and then convert the list to a numpy array at the end:

```
import numpy as np
total = []
for i in range(5,15):
    thisArray = np.arange(i)
    total.append(thisArray)
total = np.asarray(total)
```

That loop makes a 2D array; you'd nest loops to produce higher dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to manipulate arrays quite like that. Instead, make a list with the same name, and append the two arrays and change it to a numpy array like so:

```
arraytotal[]
array1 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
arraytotal.append[array1]
np.array(arraytotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use np.concatenate() like this :

```
arraytotal = np.concatenate(([array1], [array2]))
```

This results in the following 2D array.

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.